# Google Cloud SQL information schema is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, information-schema

When running a query that request information_schema, it runs very slow. an example:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
===============================
1 row(s) returned
0.344 sec / 0.000083 sec
```

MySQL documentation recommends changing the `innodb_stats_on_metadata` to false; in order to avoid analyzing tables upon selecting the schema, but Google prevents that since `root` user has no `super` privilege.

Is there any way to work around this performance issue?

Comment: Is that query run with hot or cold data?

Comment: Personally I think count(*) is a lousy performance indicator...

Comment: Use `select * . . . limit 10`.

Comment: okay I tried this one:
    `SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'COLLATIONS'
     LIMIT 20
    ===============================
    6 row(s) returned
    0.492 sec / 0.00017 sec`
but results were not better

Comment: @jarlh I didn't get your question, I am queering the information schema.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is creating a replica of the columns  information table:

```
create table INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

This prevents analyzing tables upon information retrieval, but you have to keep table content updated manually every time you make changes on any table of the target schema.